# Subtraction matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to get the subtraction matrix, the matrix obtained by subtracting each row from other rows. My MWE is below (not working as expected). The resulting matrix should be 36*3 containing subtracted values of each row from other rows. Thanks

```
X <-
  matrix(
    data=
    c(
        5, 9, 20
      , 6, 11, 2
      , 4, 5, 20
      , 6, 9, 46
      , 5, 7, 1
      , 3, 1, 12
      )
      , nrow = 6
      , ncol = 3
      , byrow=TRUE
      )

XSub <-
  matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(X)^2, ncol=ncol(X))

for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(X)){
    XSub[i+j-1, ] <- X[i, ]-X[j,]
    }
    }
XSub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you might want (avoids using a loop):

```
X <-
  matrix(
    data=
    c(
        5, 9, 20
      , 6, 11, 2
      , 4, 5, 20
      , 6, 9, 46
      , 5, 7, 1
      , 3, 1, 12
      )
      , nrow = 6
      , ncol = 3
      , byrow=TRUE
      )

comb <- expand.grid(x1=1:nrow(X), x2=1:nrow(X))
XSub <- X[comb$x1,] - X[comb$x2,]
rownames(XSub) <- paste(comb$x1, comb$x2, sep="-")
```

Results in the following:

```
> XSub
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
1-1    0    0    0
2-1    1    2  -18
3-1   -1   -4    0
4-1    1    0   26
5-1    0   -2  -19
6-1   -2   -8   -8
1-2   -1   -2   18
2-2    0    0    0
3-2   -2   -6   18
4-2    0   -2   44
5-2   -1   -4   -1
6-2   -3  -10   10
1-3    1    4    0
2-3    2    6  -18
3-3    0    0    0
4-3    2    4   26
5-3    1    2  -19
6-3   -1   -4   -8
1-4   -1    0  -26
2-4    0    2  -44
3-4   -2   -4  -26
4-4    0    0    0
5-4   -1   -2  -45
6-4   -3   -8  -34
1-5    0    2   19
2-5    1    4    1
3-5   -1   -2   19
4-5    1    2   45
5-5    0    0    0
6-5   -2   -6   11
1-6    2    8    8
2-6    3   10  -10
3-6    1    4    8
4-6    3    8   34
5-6    2    6  -11
6-6    0    0    0
```