# Finding "similar" rows performing a conditional join with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

Say I got a data.table (can also be data.frame, doesn't matter to me) which has numeric columns a, b, c, d and e. 
Each row of the table represents an article and a-e are numeric characteristics of the articles.

What I want to find out is which articles are similar to each other, based on columns a, b and c. 
*I define "similar" by allowing a, b and c to vary +/- 1 at most.* 
That is, article x is similar to article y if neither a, b nor c differs by more than 1. Their values for d and e don't matter and may differ significantly.

I've already tried a couple of approaches but didn't get the desired result. What I want to achieve is to get a result table which contains only those rows that are similar to at least one other row. Plus, duplicates must be excluded.

Particularly, I'm wondering if this is possible using the **sqldf** library. My idea is to somehow join the table with itself under the given conditions, but I don't get it together properly. Any ideas (not necessarily using **sqldf**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose our input data frame is the built-in 11x8 `anscombe` data frame.  Its first three column names are `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. Then here are some solutions.

**1) sqldf**  This returns the pairs of row numbers of similar rows:

```
library(sqldf)

ans <- anscombe
ans$id <- 1:nrow(ans)

sqldf("select a.id, b.id 
       from ans a 
       join ans b on abs(a.x1 - b.x1) <= 1 and 
                     abs(a.x2 - b.x2) <= 1 and 
                     abs(a.x3 - b.x3) <= 1")
```

Add another condition `and a.id < b.id` if each row should not be paired with itself and if we want to exclude the reverse of each pair or add `and not a.id = b.id` to just exclude self pairs.

**2) dist** This returns a matrix `m` whose i,j-th element is 1 if rows i and j are similar and 0 if not based on columns 1, 2 and 3.

```
# matrix of pairs (1 = similar, 0 = not)
m <- (as.matrix(dist(anscombe[1:3], method = "maximum")) <= 1) + 0
```

giving:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0
2  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  1  0
3  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1  0  0
4  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0
5  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  0  0
6  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0
7  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1  1
8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  1
9  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1  0  0
10 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1  0
11 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0  1
```

We could add `m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- 0` to exclude self pairs and the reverse of each pair if desired or `diag(m) <- 0` to just exclude self pairs.

We can create a data frame of similar row number pairs like this.  To keep the output short we have excluded self pairs and the reverse of each pair.

```
# two-column data.frame of pairs excluding self pairs and reverses
subset(as.data.frame.table(m), c(Var1) < c(Var2) & Freq == 1)[1:2]
```

giving:

```
    Var1 Var2
34     1    4
35     2    4
45     1    5
58     3    6
91     3    9
93     5    9
101    2   10
106    7   10
117    7   11
118    8   11
```

Here is a network graph of the above.  Note that answer continues after the graph:

```
# network graph
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(m)
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

```
# raster plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame.table(m), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = factor(Freq))) + 
       geom_raster()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great answer and very helpful, especially the sqldf example. There is still one thing that bothers me: After implementing the sqldf solution, some solutions are ambiguous because they are a subset of another solution. Example: a.id = 1 has 10, 11, and 123 as b.id entries. At the same time, a.id = 10 has 11 and 123 as b.id entries.

I don't want the last two rows to appear since they are implicitly covered by the first three rows. Is there a way to solve this issue directly in the sql statement or do we need to do this afterwards? I can only think of the latter unfortunately

Comment: Just because row 1 is similar to row 10 and to  row 11 it does not follow that row 10 is similar to row 11.    For example, consider the situation where row 1 = (0, 0, 0), row 10 =  (-1, 0, 0) and row 11 = (1, 0, 0).   Here, row 10 and row 11 are not similar even though they are both similar to row 1.

Comment: You're correct. But still, case 1 = (0, 0, 0), row 10 = (1, 0, 0) and row 11 = (0.5, 0, 0) would lead to the case I described in my last comment. I need a way to remove these subsets of solutions.

Comment: In terms of the example in the answer try: `g.mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(g); get.data.frame(g.mst, what = "edges")`

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to R so don't expect to much.

What if you create from your values (which are basically vectors) a matrix with the distance from the two values. So you can find those combinations which have a difference of less than 1 from each other. Via this way you can find the matching (a)-pairs. Repeat this with (b) and (c) and find those which are included in all pairs.

Alternatively this can probably be done as a cube as well.

Just as a thought hint.

Comment: This might be the solution to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434838/subtraction-matrix-in-r